# My javascript code does not work if there are linebreaks in a var?

Tags: javascript

```
var a = {"name":"ab
ac", age="112"};
alert(typeof a);
```

My code does not run. However if i change it to

```
var a = {"name":"abac", age:"112"};
alert(typeof a);
```

It runs properly. But the problem is that this var a I get from a GET call to a url and it appears as this only.Is there a way i can change it in code to get it working? I am new to Javascript.

I make a get call to a url. the responseText i  get is

```
    var a = {"name":"ab
ac", "age":112};
```

whereas i want it to be of type

```
 var a= {"name":"abac", age="112"};
```

because the above a is not being recognized by javascript. My question is i cannot manually put a "\" char in the resposeText since all that is happening inside code. Is there some code that can do it for me?

Comment: `But the problem is that this var a I get from a GET call to a url ` can you show us this request too please?

Comment: You can't put a linebreak in a string without escaping it somehow.

Comment: Or you can take advantage of ES6's template strings, using backticks. They allow for multi-line strings.

Comment: So, you are getting back source code as response from the server? That's not great. The server should return JSON instead.

Answer (score 1):

Use line-continuation "\" symbol as the last character on the line before the break:

```
var a = {"name":"ab\
ac", age:"112"};
```

Comment: line-continuation character? this is just escaping the line break.

Answer (score 1):

There are two problems

```
var a = {"name":"ab \ 
ac", age:"112"}; //notice : in place of =
alert(typeof a);
```

1. You need to add `\` in case a **string** has to be continued to next line.
2. Key value has to be separated by `:` not `=`

Comment: yeah but the problem is i cannot change var a , it is something i am getting from a get call from a url?

Comment: @KanikaMidha can you share how you are getting this?

Comment: @Kanika: I think what we are all confused about is how a URL query parameter ends up in your JavaScript *source code*.

Comment: I make a get request to a URL and the xhttp.responseText that I get is in this form.

Comment: @KanikaMidha what is `this form` ? If you are already getting this `a` from responseText then your data is already escaped.